# Bitcoin Core for Mac not syncing, can't access private key to export coins to other wallet

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, synchronization, private-key-export

Wondering if you can help me guys, I'm new to using bitcoins and recently downloaded Bitcoin Core to my MacBook. I stupidly sent bitcoins to my wallet without realising i had to sync first, but it's been syncing for a week now and still has 1 year 46 weeks to go. It's barely altered in 2 days so i've given up waiting and have been using blockchaininfo's online wallet, so I want to get those bitcoins transferred to there if possible.

I've read the threads about exporting the private key, but the problem is I don't know the passphrase to access it as i was never prompted to create one, I just installed it and started syncing. Also, Blockchain's 'desktop sync' feature that people have mentioned doesn't appear anywhere in my account, so i can't do that either. Is there any other way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: If you never encrypted your wallet, it is unencrypted, and you don't need any password.

Comment: It's saying it's locked and encrypted though, and asks for a passphrase if i try to send a payment? I definitely didn't set one.

Comment: Bitcoin Core never encrypts by default. If it says it is encrypted, it must explicitly have been encrypted by someome.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's 6 years old and from the comment it looks like it's a dead-end. There isn't a good answer to "i haven't encrypted my wallet but it's encrypted what gives?".